# Dictionary using dict comprehensions where we have maximum value for a key

Tags: python

I Have a nested dictionary like this

```
{'adcellh': {'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'h': 1},
 'llfechh': {'l': 2, 'e': 1, 'h': 2},
 'hkleeemvt': {'h': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 3}}
```

I want to generate output dictionary like

```
{'e': 3, 'l': 2, 'h': 2}
```

Here I want to generate dictionary keys with their maximum value. To solve this I used following solution. Please note, that each dictionary has the same keys.

```
    s={}
    for i in d.values():
        for j in i:
        
            if j in s and s[j]>i[j]:
                continue
            else:
                 s[j]=i[j]
```

Can someone help to get same output using dict comprehension or another one-line solution? I don't want to use Python libraries like collections or any other library which is not usually available in Assessment editor.

Comment: Why do you need a one-line solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple dict comprehensions that will do it.  First, define `d` as follows:

```
d = {'adcellh': {'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'h': 1},
     'llfechh': {'l': 2, 'e': 1, 'h': 2},
     'hkleeemvt': {'h': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 3}}
```

You can now get the desired result dict with:

```
r = {k2 : max(d3[k2] for d3 in d.values())
     for k2 in next(iter(d.values()))}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
r = {k2 : max(d3[k2] for d3 in d.values())
     for k2 in d[next(iter(d))]}
```

These are both one-liners.  I split the long lines to make them more readable, but you could put it all on a single line if desired.

These both produce the following dict for `r`:

```
{'e': 3, 'l': 2, 'h': 2}
```

Note that the idiom `next(iter(x))` is just a way of choosing the first element of an iterable `x` (but for this application, we don't care which element we get so the order doesn't matter).  This is done to obtain the set of keys in the result dict, relying on the fact that all of the dictionaries have the same keys.  This idiom is preferred over doing something like `list(x)[0]`, which would needlessly create a list of all of the elements of the iterable `x` just to choose one of them.

Everything else is relatively straightforward.

This solution avoids creating any temporary lists, sets, etc., which serve no purpose other than to allocate and then discard memory, which is undesirable.  It also runs in linear time (in the total number of values).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `next` or `iter` you can use this line of code:

```py
{ke: (max([val.get(ke) for val in d.values()])) for ke in list(set([y for x in [list(k.keys()) for k in d.values()] for y in x]))}
```

It can be written in less code but I tried not to use `next` or `iter` as a challenge.

Comment: Creating temporary lists for no reason is inefficient.  The preferred idiom for choosing an element of an iterable  is `next(iter(x))`, as shown in my solution.  The alternative is to use `list(x)[0]`, but that creates an entire throwaway list, which should be avoided.  A good solution should not create any temporary lists, dicts, sets, etc.  See if you can find a solution that uses constant (i.e. O(1)) extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly with `sorted` function (to shift max value to the front of the sequence of entries):

```
s = dict(sorted(((k, v) for d in d.values() for k, v in d.items())))
```

---

```
{'e': 3, 'h': 2, 'l': 2}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't run in linear time, which could be a problem is there are lots and lots of small dicts.  An optimal solution should run in linear time (in the total number of values).